# Why do I get a HTML unescaped context menu in Chrome?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, emoji, contextual-menu

When I right click on any of the input enabled controls in Chrome on my macOS Sierra, I now-a-days get this first option, which I could get using <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>. Looks like something's broken?

See the second item here:

[image: preview]

On textareas (in Ask Different too):

[image: textarea]

Comment: Ah, this is fixed in new update of macOS... `:)`

Comment: Why not just post an answer explaining that it was resolved with the update? This way it'll be helpful to others who find themselves in the same situation. Be sure to explain what versions of macOS was involved.

Comment: @Monomeeth Sure, will do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this issue has been fixed via the next update. Sorry for the late response.

[image: preview]